# Youtube player on Codenameone

Tags: java, video, youtube, codenameone, media

I've been working on a codenameone app recently, and one of the app features is to play the youtube video that i chose form a list.
The list is fullfilled with a "Movie" objects, and the movie contains an embed youtube URL, for an example "https://www.youtube.com/embed/r6VO3zaBJGY".
In my form, I created WebBrowser named "player" and that's what I did :

```
player = new WebBrowser();
String integrationCode= "<iframe src=\"" +videoUrl+"\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"autoplay; encrypted-media\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
 player.setPage(integrationCode, null);
myForm.add(player);
```

it works, and I got the youtube player, but it looks aweful, and I can't put the player on full-screen.
Is there any alternative solution to play a video from a youtube URL ? or at least how can I put it on full-screen.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the way this looks on the simulator is different from the way it will appear on the device as youtube detects the device and adapts the rendering to it. The HTML rendering on the simulator is limited by what's available on JavaSE.

You can also customize the player appearance with a lot of optional arguments listed here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters